# BULK COLLECT INTO inside OPEN cursor FOR SELECT... doesn't populate collection

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure, which returns cursor as an output parameter. Inside SP the output cursor variable is opened as SELECT statement. I was to reuse records from this cursor for the following logic in the SP, and used BULK COLLECT clause to store them in a nested table. But found out, that without any exception this nested table is not populated.
I wrote a simple example to illustrate this behavior:

```
create table temp_table as
select 1 as col1 from dual
union all
select 2 as col1 from dual;

declare
  v_cur sys_refcursor;
  v_rec temp_table%rowtype;
  procedure get_cursor(v_cur OUT sys_refcursor) is
    type typ_temp_tab_tab is table of temp_table%rowtype;
    v_tab typ_temp_tab_tab;
  begin
    v_tab:=typ_temp_tab_tab();
    open v_cur for 
      select * 
      bulk collect into v_tab
        from temp_table;
    dbms_output.put_line('nested table''s records num: '||v_tab.count);
  end;
begin
  get_cursor(v_cur);
  dbms_output.put_line('values in cursor: ');
  loop
    fetch v_cur into v_rec;
    exit when v_cur%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line('>>'||v_rec.col1);   
  end loop;
end;
/
drop table temp_table;
```

And output is:

> ```
> nested table's records num: 0
> values in cursor: 
> >>1
> >>2
> ```

Do you have any idea why it's not working and what is the best practice to reuse cursor's records inside a SP?

Comment: You can't do both. (I'm surprised it doesn't complain about that syntax). You can't get the cursor contents without consuming it, so if you looped to populate the nested table the caller wouldn't see anything left in the cursor. Why do you need both? And can the nested table be declared at schema level, instead of as a local PL/SQL type?

Comment: @AlexPoole, Thanks! Yes, it seems so. Without consuming the cursor with looping through it nested table can't be populated. I'm also wondering why such a syntax doesn't cause an error. I need it because the first I should return a cursor to application and the second I need use the same result set to insert it. I can wrap this query in a table-function, but it will look a bit more complicated and I'll need to implement standalone nested table type.

Comment: If you are going to create a standalone table type you only need to perform the query once - bulk collect the query and then open the cursor against the collection.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, it is what I've done already. I was trying to avoid both standalone type and using the same query twice. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't write:

```
open v_cur for 
      select * 
      bulk collect into v_tab
        from temp_table;
```

You just need:

```
  select * 
  bulk collect into v_tab
    from temp_table;
```

No "`open v_cur for`".

Unfortunately, I think that means that you cannot both (A) have the data in a nested table and (B) return the open cursor to the caller without running the query twice.  Oracle must fetch all the rows in the cursor to perform the `BULK COLLECT` after which point the cursor would be useless to pass back to the caller.

Comment: Thank you! When I wrote my code and Oracle was't complaining I was glad that I found a way to do A and B simultaneously. Unfortunately I was wrong:) I will implement a standalone table type and rewrite this code.

Comment: If you really want the results both (A) populated in a PL/SQL collection and (B) passed back to the caller as an open cursor, you could do that without executing the query twice by first doing the BULK COLLECT into the collection, as I have shown in my answer and then doing `OPEN v_cur FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(temp_table)`.  For that to work though, you need to make `typ_temp_tab_tab` an `OBJECT` in the database.  Or, if you are running 12c, you can define the `TYPE` in a package specification and use it.

Comment: Thanks, I've already implemented that exactly in the way described by you. I wish we all have had 12c:)